# Give Role Permission to 1 Admin Configuration area?

Tags: users, configuration

Is there a simple way to give access to 1 panel of options within `Administration Configuration`? I made a custom module with settings under `/admin/config/mymodule` and it shows up as a block with links in the admin config area.

But I cant see how to easily say `Role X` can access that -- without giving global `access admin configuration` in Permissions, which lets them see everything there :(.

My example hook_menu is:

```
function predeparture_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/eap-predeparture'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage Site',
    'description' => 'upload the valid predeparture csv file from this page.',
    'position' => 'left',
    'weight' => -100,
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
  );
  // Need at least one child item before your section will appear.
  $items['admin/config/eap-predeparture/list'] = array(
    'title' => 'Student Predeparture List',
    'description' => 'Upload, Revise or Rebuild the student perm list to administer access to the predeparture survey.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('predeparture_csv_admin_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'weight' => 10,
  );
  $items['admin/config/eap-predeparture/incomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Not Yet Completed Orientation Report',
    'description' => 'These students have not completed the Predeparture survey based on those in the CSV file.',
    'page callback' => 'predeparture_incomplete_listing',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'weight' => 20,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own permission in your module

```
function predeparture_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then your menu item should have

```
'access arguments' => array('administer my module')
```

And check this permission for the role you want in the permissions page: admin/people/permissions

Comment: I used this solution to enable access. But they cant see the menu path in like the Admin Menu or anywhere -- they have to goto the URL directly. Any idea how to see the `Admin Configuration` but dissallow all modules that aren't my own for X role ? .... wizardy in `hook_menu_alter` ?

Comment: you could create a custom link to access directly to this page

Comment: [Custom Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/config_perms) can maybe help you

Comment: thanks. `Custom Permissions` looks like what I've been looking for -- your general solution is still great.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own "access callback" function returning TRUE just if the current user have the role you choose. Something like this:

```
function predeparture_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/config/eap-predeparture'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage Site',
    'description' => 'upload the valid predeparture csv file from this page.',
    'position' => 'left',
    'weight' => -100,
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'access callback' => 'my_access_callback',
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
  );

function my_access_callback() {
  global $user;
  return in_array('the role', $user->roles);
}
```